# Masking UIImage in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'am trying to create profile picture image with custom shape pattern with using masking in ios. Here is what i've used to create masked image :

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);

    // returns new image with mask applied
    return maskedImage;
}
```

After implementing instance , i am calling : *(_profileImage is global UIImage)

```
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"maskProfilePicture.png"];

UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:_profileImage withMask:maskImage];
```

and result (Image should be added in subview of mask. But it seems , mask image overlap on Image that need to be masked ):

[image: masked image]

The mask image  : (Maybe mask image properties are wrong that i created in photoshop :)

[image: Mask Image]

Comment: The Core Graphics calls look correct. Can you post the mask image you are using? According to the docs, it must be in the DeviceGray color space, and must not have an alpha component.

Comment: I've added mask image but it's white , that's why it seems there's nothing :)))

Comment: naive comment: shouldn't the mask be black?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella not naïve at all. :-)

Comment: Can someone explain me , why these borders appear ? :( - http://prntscr.com/1z5nxw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Core Graphics calls look correct.

Change the mask image to be have a black where you want the image to show through, and white elsewhere.

[image: mask image]

Comment: Thank you for your help , it works fine except giving white border to mask image :/

Comment: @JasonHarwig, how can I add mask to `UIView` that will be rotated, but make this mask tied to bottom of that `UIView` and won't rotate with UIView? I asked question about that but nobody answered, maybe you know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Any idea about the reverse masking.(Reverse of above process).Means I want to remove the fill area(make it transparent) and Transparent area with fill.

Comment: @Milanpatel, Invert colors of the mask image. `convert mask.png -negate inverted.png`

Comment: @JasonHarwig,please see my question on stack overflow.   ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122370/masking-and-reverse-masking-in-imageview-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can use CALayer's mask property to achieve the result.

[CALayer Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask)

Your masking layer should be transparent in places where you want to cut out the image.